# convert string to date (format year quarter) in pyspark

Tags: date, pyspark

I have a below dataframe with column :

df

```
id dt
1  2016/2017 Q2
2  2017/2018 Q1
3  2018/2019 Q2
```

output:

df

```
id date
1  2016-07-01
2  2017-04-01
3  2018-07-01
```

I need to convert them into date in pyspark Usually, I use the below code to convert to date by specifying format but couldn't find any format for quarter, please could you advise.

code: `F.from_unixtime(F.unix_timestamp(date_str, fmt)).cast("date")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no **direct function/format** that will return quarter date.

We need to use `when` statement (or) `udf` for this case.

**Example:**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([("1","2016/2017 Q2"),("2","2017/2018 Q1"),("3","2018/2019 Q3"),("4","2019/2020 Q4")],["id","dt"])

#4 quarters in an year
df.withColumn("date",
    when(lower(reverse(split(col("dt")," "))[0]) == "q1",concat_ws("-",substring(col("dt"),0,4),lit("01-01")).cast("date")).\
    when(lower(reverse(split(col("dt")," "))[0]) == "q2",concat_ws("-",substring(col("dt"),0,4),lit("04-01")).cast("date")).\
    when(lower(reverse(split(col("dt")," "))[0]) == "q3",concat_ws("-",substring(col("dt"),0,4),lit("07-01")).cast("date")).\
    when(lower(reverse(split(col("dt")," "))[0]) == "q4",concat_ws("-",substring(col("dt"),0,4),lit("10-01")).cast("date")).\
    otherwise(lit("Quarter not found"))).show()

#+---+------------+----------+
#| id|          dt|      date|
#+---+------------+----------+
#|  1|2016/2017 Q2|2016-04-01|
#|  2|2017/2018 Q1|2017-01-01|
#|  3|2018/2019 Q3|2018-07-01|
#|  4|2019/2020 Q4|2019-10-01|
#+---+------------+----------+
```